# Displaying an image using Play

Tags: playframework

I want to display a picture such as for a background for a website or for a container(div).
I have been trying to use . 
I get the error: No route able to display file /public/images/logo.png (file not found) was found.

Comment: where did you get the error message? Play console? Can you post more information? E.g. copy the error message from console instead typing with your own words, the content of your route file, the directory structure of your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from your description, I assume that in your view somewhere you have

```
<img src="@{'/public/images/logo.png'}" />
```

If you are getting a routes error, it is because the file does not exist. So, check a few things.

1. Check the file exists in the /public/images directory
2. Check that the case (uppercase/lowercase) is correct, as linux OS's will complain
3. check you have not deleted the route for public static assets in your routes file
4. Check your routes file has not superseded the public route with a different entry further up.

Comment: Thanks. #2 was the culprit for me. The extension of the image was in uppercase. Now all seems to be well.